# Is there a way to use the methods of a string created JOptionPane? (Java)

Tags: java, identifier

I've googled the holy bejaysus out of it and just can't find the right combination of words. How do I use methods on something with no identifier? For instance;

```
String inputBio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, heroPane, "Please enter details...", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

How do I refer to that dialog?

Comment: Well, I don't understand your question..

Comment: If I, for instance, wanted to change the colouring of a normally constructed pane (`JOptionPane myPane = new JOptionPane();`) i would use `myPane.setBackground(Color.RED);` or some such, but without having to declare a unique identifier I'm not sure how to refer to it. I know I could just use the normal way but it's bugging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to assign the value typed into the input box to the String? You need to create an Integer and assign it to the JOptionPane.showInputDialog, then use the constructor to instantiate a new instance of the Input Dialog with the options you want.

Now, to extract the data, add an IF statement and go through the possible options presented to the user. If you added JoptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION then you have two options: OK and CANCEL.
The IF statement should be: If the user selected OK, extract the string, ELSE do whatever you want to do.

The string should be extracted from the textfield that was created (which I assume is somewhere in the 'heroPane')

Here's how that would look in code

```
//the string we use for input
String inputBio;

int optionBox = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, heroPane, "Please enter details...", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
//now the integer value represents the option selected (OK or CANCEL)
//All we need to do is extract the data and assign it to the string

if (optionBox == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
//the OK option
inputBio = nameOfYourTextField.getText();

} else {
// we have a CANCEL option
}
```

You could, of course, do it without an IF statement, but make sure you handle all of the options accordingly

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the comprehensive answer. +1 for you sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a reference to the `JOptionPane`, you cannot use the `showInputDialog` convenience methods. You will need to construct a `JOptionPane` object.

Comment: Convenience methods, eh!? This is the first I have heard of these (though i have clearly been using them). Thank you for your prompt response, good sir!